# Workflow with Flash Pro CS6 and FlashDevelop: Using fla and swc to store assets

Tags: actionscript-3, assets, flashdevelop

I am using this tutorial:

http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3:FlexAndFlashCS3Workflow

In the past older versions of Flash Pro I was able to complete these steps:

- right-click on the symbol in the Library panel, select "Linkage..." dialog,
- check "Export for ActionScript" and fill in the symbol name (ie. MySymbol_design or assets.MySymbol_design),
- do not change the base class (ie. flash.display.MovieClip).

Right now, I am stuck at that part. Any hints?

What I wish to do is:

1. Use fla for the artist to store assets.
2. Publish to swc
3. Extract the assets in FlashDevelop by creating an instance of their class.

... How is this done in CS6?

To clear things up, this is what I see when I right click a Flash symbol:

[image]

Comment: There is no menu called Linkage in the dialog and I did not find any mention of "Export for ActionScript" in the help files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as you right-clicked a symbol on stage. You should right-click the symbol in your library panel instead. There you have "Properties" where you can mark a symbol to be exported for Actionscript. If you don't place the symbol on stage, you'll also have to tick the "export to first frame" option.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the 'Advanced' expandable menu in properties. So everything else is the same as it used to be?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I'm not aware of any changes in that regard.

Comment: Great it is working!